# Enable Tablet Mode on Windows 10 through Code?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Ive read various way on how to detect if a Windows 10 device is in Tablet Mode, most notably the topic below;

[How can I detect when Window 10 enters tablet mode in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153664/how-can-i-detect-when-window-10-enters-tablet-mode-in-a-windows-forms-applicatio)

I would like to enable/disable Tablet Mode through code (.Net C#) but I cant find any resources to achieve this. Ive tried changing the registry key and sending a HWND_BROADCAST that a change has occurred but this doesn't initiate the change to tablet mode.

Ive also tried using Spy++ style applications but cant see the messages being sent.

Does a method exist to do this?

Comment: I'm quite sure this method doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidLeitner There has to be some event, as Microsoft has taken advantage of it in their apps. It may not be exposed in the .NET Framework, but it will exist in the WinAPI somewhere.

Comment: @GregoryABeamer thanks for the comments. Yes I expect it its buried in the WinAPI somewhere. I had already trawled the UWP samples and most are related to handling the change to tablet mode and not initiating it.

Comment: @gdbgeek You want to force someone into tablet mode?

Comment: @GregoryABeamer almost correct.I have a 2-in-1 device that does not automatically switch to tablet mode when I undock the keyboard. I can detect when the keyboard is removed. When this occurs I would like to enable tablet mode.

Comment: Using a windows form application I can see the message being broadcast but doing the same from my application doesnt change the mode.

Comment: @gdbgeek Did you get any solution to enable tablet mode in code ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no real way to do this in C#. Of course you can change the registry key, but you will need a log off/on to change from or to tablet mode.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode
```

Enable: 1 or disable 0

Since I had a problem that my WPF-App will not appear on startup with tablet mode on, I used a AutoHotKey script.
You can create a .exe as well.
Source: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=15619

```
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines -1
ListLines Off
#NoTrayIcon 


TABLETMODESTATE_DESKTOPMODE := 0x0
TABLETMODESTATE_TABLETMODE := 0x1

TabletModeController_GetMode(TabletModeController, ByRef mode) {
    return DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(TabletModeController+0),3*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", TabletModeController, "UInt*", mode)
}

TabletModeController_SetMode(TabletModeController, _TABLETMODESTATE, _TMCTRIGGER := 4) {
    return DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(TabletModeController+0),4*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", TabletModeController, "UInt", _TABLETMODESTATE, "UInt", _TMCTRIGGER)  
}

ImmersiveShell := ComObjCreate("{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}", "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
TabletModeController := ComObjQuery(ImmersiveShell, "{4fda780a-acd2-41f7-b4f2-ebe674c9bf2a}", "{4fda780a-acd2-41f7-b4f2-ebe674c9bf2a}")

if (TabletModeController_GetMode(TabletModeController, mode) == 0)
    TabletModeController_SetMode(TabletModeController, mode == TABLETMODESTATE_DESKTOPMODE ? TABLETMODESTATE_TABLETMODE : TABLETMODESTATE_DESKTOPMODE)

ObjRelease(TabletModeController), TabletModeController := 0
ObjRelease(ImmersiveShell), ImmersiveShell := 0 ; Can be freed after TabletModeController is created, instead
```

Answer (score 1):

Poke around in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) - You will want to focus on the samples for user interaction mode.

NOTE: This is for UWP (Universal Windows Platform), aka Windows 10+, and you will need code for other versions of Windows if you are not targeting Win 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of j-krue and the AutoHotKey script. Source: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=15619.
The following code was tested in Windows 10 and works properly to switch tablet mode without re-login or reboot.

```
sruct ITabletModeController : IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetMode(int* piMode) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetMode(int iMode, int iModeTrigger) = 0;
};

// IID_IServiceProvider: {6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}
// CLSID_ImmersiveShell: {C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ImmersiveShell, 0xC2F03A33, 0x21F5, 0x47FA, 0xB4, 0xBB, 0x15, 0x63, 0x62, 0xA2, 0xF2, 0x39);
DEFINE_GUID(IID_ITabletModeController, 0x4FDA780A, 0xACD2, 0x41F7, 0xB4, 0xF2, 0xEB, 0xE6, 0x74, 0xC9, 0xBF, 0x2A);
static void EnableTabletMode(BOOL bEnable)
{
    ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    IServiceProvider* pServiceProvider = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ImmersiveShell, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IServiceProvider, (PVOID*)&pServiceProvider);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ITabletModeController* pTabletController = NULL;
        hr = pServiceProvider->QueryService(IID_ITabletModeController, IID_ITabletModeController, (void**)&pTabletController);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pTabletController)
        {
            // iMode: 0 = Desktop, 1 = Tablet
            int iMode = -1;
            hr = pTabletController->GetMode(&iMode);
            int iToMode = bEnable ? 1 : 0;
            if (iMode != -1 && iMode != iToMode)
            {
                hr = pTabletController->SetMode(iToMode, 4);
            }
            pTabletController->Release();
        }
        pServiceProvider->Release();
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```