# Know when Windows 10 are Tablet Mode - Windows 10 / Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I work on Universal App for Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile.
Does anyone know how to check if Windows 10 is running on Tablet Mode?

I found this question here but that is for Windows Forms: [How can I detect when Window 10 enters tablet mode in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153664/how-can-i-detect-when-window-10-enters-tablet-mode-in-a-windows-forms-applicatio)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You [query the UserInteractionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uiviewsettings.userinteractionmode.aspx) - this is the sample code from that link

```
switch(UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode)
{
  case UserInteractionMode.Mouse:
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MouseLayout", true);
    break;

  case UserInteractionMode.Touch:
  default:
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "TouchLayout", true);
    break;
}
```

Comment: case UserInteractionMode.Touch: default: should be touch mode. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code below can help you:

```
UIViewSettings^ uiViewSettings = UIViewSettings::GetForCurrentView();
UserInteractionMode mode = uiViewSettings->UserInteractionMode;
switch (mode)
{
case UserInteractionMode::Touch:
  // PC is in tablet mode or other touch-first environment
  break;

case UserInteractionMode::Mouse:
  // PC is not in tablet mode or other mouse-first environment
  break;
}
```