# How to determine if a WPF .NET application has entered Windows 10 tablet mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Let me start by saying that I've read similar questions:

[How can I detect when Window 10 enters tablet mode in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153664/how-can-i-detect-when-window-10-enters-tablet-mode-in-a-windows-forms-applicatio)

[Know when Windows 10 are Tablet Mode - Windows 10 / Windows 10 Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041370/know-when-windows-10-are-tablet-mode-windows-10-windows-10-mobile)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/0610868f-8c30-4749-beac-510063b73913/about-windows-10-tablet-mode-api?forum=windowsuidevelopment

Through these questions I've determined through the registry settings if my WPF application, running on my surface, has entered tablet mode.

I can also tell that by looking at the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanging if the surface has a keyboard attached or not (using GetSystemMetrics for SM_CONVERTABLESLATEMODE = 0x2003 and SM_SYSTEMDOCKED = 0x2004) OR if the machine running the application is a tablet (SM_TABLETPC = 0x56).

I don't like having to look at the registery settings and I would like to know if there is another way of telling if the surface has entered tablet mode?  This is not a UWP app, so as far as I know, I can not use [UIViewSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uiviewsettings.userinteractionmode.aspx).