# How to detect if Windows 10 is in tablet mode

Tags: winapi, windows-10, tablet-pc

I'm trying to find a method to detect if Windows 10 is in tablet mode or not. Please note, this is not about querying whether the user has a Tablet PC or not - that can be solved with `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CONVERTIBLESLATEMODE)`. In my case the above function always returns 0 - whether Win10 is in tablet mode or not.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106246/how-to-detect-tablet-mode) thread without an epilogue seems to  suggest that there is no WinAPI call that could detect Tablet mode. I hope that isn't the case, since there are different WM messages posted by the OS if it's in tablet mode or not. In tablet mode [WM_SHOWWINDOW isn't sent](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/issues/40) which means I need to address the launching of the application differently if Windows 10 is in tablet mode.

I could just move the code that is currently triggered after receiving the `WM_SHOWWINDOW` message somewhere else (just after `ShowWindow` is called), but then I get a `WM_DPICHANGED` message with null parameters.

Comment: Can GetSystemMetrics() (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) with  SM_TABLETPC help?

Comment: [Use UserInteractionMode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160706-00/?p=93815)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIViewSettings.UserInteractionMode @Raymond pointed out.

Refer to "[Tablet mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/continuum)"  "[How can I detect whether my PC is in tablet mode?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=93815)"

Comment: Um, this is not documented or supported. Use the supported API: UserInteractionMode.

Comment: The samples on the blog from @RaymondChen and on the Windows docs page mentioned by @RitaHan seem to be what I'm looking for. However after implementing them, I get a `pointer to incomplete type not allowed` message for `uiViewSettingsInterop->GetForWindow` even though I'm including `UIViewSettingsInterop.h
`. My `NTDDI_VERSION` is 0x0603 (targeting Win8.1 and up). Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `IUIViewSettingsInterop` is supported starting in Windows 10. Notice that the definition of `IUIViewSettingsInterop` is inside `#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINTHRESHOLD)`.